# Creating a table error occured, why does error occur and how can I fix this?

Tags: sql

Why does error occur and how can I fix this?
This is my code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mixed_martial_art (
Fighter_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL 
City VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Specialty VARCHAR (50)REFERENCES ONE_FC(Fighter_id)
gym VARCHAR (75),
wins  SMALLINT,
loses SMALLINT,
draws SMALLINT)
```

Comment: _"Why does error occur"_ You forgot to tell what Error and to mention the `DBMS` you're using

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a comma after `Country VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL` and you didn't declare the foreign key correctly.

```sql
CREATE TABLE mixed_martial_art (
Fighter_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Specialty VARCHAR (50),
gym VARCHAR (75),
wins  SMALLINT,
loses SMALLINT,
draws SMALLINT,
FOREIGN KEY (Specialty) REFERENCES ONE_FC(Fighter_id))
```